# Integrating QnAMaker and Luis - Exception Stack is empty

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-qna-maker

Using Luis dialog if the intent is none, I want to forward to QnAMakerDialog for matching QnAPair.

If pair is found, return the answer and return to luis stack.  If a pair is not send message "Sorry I don't know that" and return to luis stack awaiting another message.

I am successfully getting response from `await context.Forward(qnaDialog, AfterQnADialog, messageToForward, CancellationToken.None)`.  After the response is returned the emulator throws `Exception Stack is empty [File Type 'text/plain']`

I think the error is in *AfterQnADialog* but not sure how to fix it.  Thanks in advance for your help.

**Message Controller***

```
if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
       await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootLuisDialog());
    }
```

**Luis Dialog Class**

```
[LuisIntent("")]
[LuisIntent("None")]    
public async Task None(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> message ,LuisResult result)
    {

        var qnaDialog = new QnADialog();
        var messageToForward = await message;
        await context.Forward(qnaDialog, AfterQnADialog, messageToForward, CancellationToken.None);

    }
```

...

```
private async Task AfterQnADialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
   {
        var messageHandled = await result;

        if (messageHandled == null)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("I’m not sure what you want.");
        }

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
    }
```

**QnAMakerDialog Class**

```
    [QnAMaker("<QnAMakerAppID", "QnAMakerApiKey", "I don't understand this right now! Try another query!", 0.10, 1)]
    public class QnADialog : QnAMakerDialog
    { 

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try commenting the code line :-

context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do a test with the following sample code to forward a message to the QnAMakerDialog from a LUIS dialog if no intents match, which works for me, you can refer to it.

**In LUIS dialog:**

```
[LuisIntent("None")]
public async Task NoneIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{

    await context.Forward(new QnADialog(), AfterQnADialog, context.Activity, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

**QnAMakerDialog:**

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using QnAMakerDialog;
using QnAMakerDialog.Models;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace HalChatBot.Dialogs
{

    [Serializable]
    [QnAMakerService("{subscriptionKey_here}", "{ knowledgeBaseId_here}")]
    public class QnADialog : QnAMakerDialog<object>
    {
        public override async Task NoMatchHandler(IDialogContext context, string originalQueryText)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Sorry, I couldn't find an answer for '{originalQueryText}'.");
            context.Done(false);
        }

        public override async Task DefaultMatchHandler(IDialogContext context, string originalQueryText, QnAMakerResult result)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"I found {result.Answers.Length} answer(s) that might help...{result.Answers.First().Answer}.");
            context.Done(true);
        }
    }
```

**Note**: I get same exception message: "Stack is empty" if I do not override the **NoMatchHandler** and call `context.Done` to pass control back to the parent dialog.

**Update:**

It seems that you are using [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices) in your project. If that is the case, you do not need to install [QnAMakerDialog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QnAMakerDialog/). To avoid "Stack is empty" error, you can override `RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync` and call `context.Done` to pass control back to the parent dialog.

```
[Serializable]
[QnAMaker("{subscriptionKey_here}", "{knowledgeBaseId_here}")]
public class BaiscQnaDialog : Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker.QnAMakerDialog
{
    protected override async Task RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity message, QnAMakerResults result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"I found {result.Answers.Count} answer(s) that might help...{result.Answers.First().Answer}.");
        context.Done(true);
    }
}
```

**Test result:**

[image]

Comment: I get error _"No suitable method found to override"_ for both **NoMatchHandler** and **DefaultMatchHandler** in the _QnADialog_

Comment: I installed NuGet package [QnAMakerDialog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QnAMakerDialog/).

Comment: I already have QnAMakerDialog Package installed, and ```using QnAMakerDialog``` still get the override error

Comment: Hi @Adam, I updated my reply. You can refer to it to override `RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync` and call `context.Done` to pass control back to the parent dialog

Comment: Hi @Fei, that is where the error is coming from.  I uninstalled  
 _Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker_ and kept _QnAMakerDialog_  and it fixed the override error.  When botj QnAMakerDialog  and Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker packages are installed, the method is ambiguous and it cannot resolve.  Thanks for the help.